# Will cron job start a new thread or wait for existing one to complete?

Tags: php, cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Have cron wait for job to finish before re-launching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652714/have-cron-wait-for-job-to-finish-before-re-launching)

Let's say I have a cron job set at 1 minute interval.
The processing takes 1 minute 10 seconds. My question is while the existing cron job is running, will it start a new thread for same cron job after one minute or will it wait for existing cron job to finish and then start again at 1 minute interval?

Comment: Possibly looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652714/have-cron-wait-for-job-to-finish-before-re-launching

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. How do I accept your answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand cron is single threaded. It uses a fairly straightforward algorithm that sleeps until the next calculated time for an event, wakes up and runs. However, I believe it forks and execs that job, so a running job will not block the creation of a new job. This should be fairly simple for you to test.